# How can I create an event that recurs every other day in the iPhone calendar?

Tags: iphone

How do I create an event on my I phone calendar that would occur every other day without manually putting in the 
Event on each day in the calendar?

Answer (score 3):

If you sync your iPhone calendar with your Mac, either through iTunes, MobileMe, or a free iCloud account you can just set up your event in iCal on your Mac. Choose for repeat *Custom*. Then choose for frequency *Daily* and set it to Every **2** days.

Answer (score 3):

If you are syncing the calendar via iCloud, you can also set this up using the web interface http://www.icloud.com. When creating a new event (bottom right corner, + button), set repeat to custom and enter your desired interval.